# PHP: Check if MySQL time value is greater than 5 minutes

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Difference is a MySQL time. I am trying to check if the MySQL time returned is greater than 5 minutes. I have tried the code below but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
if (strtotime($myMySQLTimeValue) > strtotime("+5 minutes",)) {
    // My code if MySQL time is greater than 5 minutes
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: populate another variable  with SELECT NOW() + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE or whatever you have instead of NOW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have the time in the format `00:06:43` then you could use the following code

```
$diff_time = "00:06:43";
$diff_arr  = split(":", $diff_time);
// Check mins and hours
if ( intval($diff_arr[1]) >= 5 || intval($diff_arr[0]) > 0) {
    echo "Time more then 5 min";
} else {
    echo "Time less then 5 min";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you retrieved mysql time by `"SELECT NOW()"`, you can use below comparison:

```
$_5minuteslater = time() + 5 * 60;
if ($mysqlTime > $_5minuteslater) {
}
```

Comment: I actually used the 'TIMEDIFF' function get the difference between two time values in the select statement. This returns a value in this format: 00:06:43